# Properly format extracted date time with python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
print a.split('/',1)
```

which returns `['27', '09/2018']`.

I need to format the extracted date time as `27/09`

Comment: what is a? Can you explain more? You might not need the extra argument as 1

Comment: Its just a parameter. Anyways I dont need that. I am more concerned about getting the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module without creating new list by splitting values

```
import re
a = "27/09/2018"
re.sub('/\d{4}$','',a)
```

Using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
import datetime
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%d/%m/%Y')
print('{}/{}'.format(date.day,date.month))
```

using [rsplit](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html)

```
a = "27/09/2018"
a.rsplit('/',1)[0] # 1 is max_splits param
```

Comment: I like how you're suggesting `re` and/or `datetime` @mad_ I've rarely considered that. Is this faster or even worth it in terms of memory usage compared to my answer? Also could you explain what re or datetime are doing exactly, or include links to these use examples?

Comment: Well yes as these methods will not create a new list which otherwise will be created by `split`. `split` solution is more readable but I think datetime solution will open new ways to deal with month and day say if you want to find the date difference. I personally avoid split wherever I can. @Jaba included the links as well

Comment: Is split slower? Or is this just for more dynamic use?

Comment: Performance variance can be seen with bigger string samples but definitely split increases the space complexity.

Comment: @mad_ this works great. thanks. I need to convert the result 27/09 into int data type but I get an error - invalid literal for int() with base 10. I have the following code: int(a.rsplit('/',1)[0])

Comment: That is not possible in this world sorry. 27/09 is a string type unless you mean 27 divided by 9

Comment: No its not a division but a date format. I want to show dates in sequence on X-axis on a chart, example for past 30 days - 27/09 28/09 29/09 30/09 01/10 .... 26/10.

Comment: First of all, post is on hold and further discussion does not make sense. You are adding up the requirement in the comment section which is not helpful for others. And, you don't need specifically integer values to plot the graphs with dates on x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for a string in the end. You may be looking for this:

```
a = "27/09/2018"
a = a.split('/')
```

This would make `a` a `list` equal to: `['27', '09', '2018']`. In order to print in the format you're looking for, use something like this:

```
print "{}/{}".format(a[0], a[1])
```

or this:

```
print a[0] + '/' + a[1]
```

Comment: You can include why OP solution failed because of extra argument related to max_splits

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
tokens = a.split("/")
print(tokens[0] + "/" + tokens[1])
```