# Split a Response in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a credit card's credential from the front-end, I am getting a 'expiry date' response in ajax `20/2020`, and i am trying to split it using python split() function.

```
x = 20/2020
```

I want result as 20 and 2020 but its coming it different ways as mentioned below, so how can i get two integers in split?

```
x.split() = ['20/2020']
x.split("/") = ["20","2020"]
```

Right now i am getting two or one string in output.

Comment: Is the above a string?

Comment: Furthermore is this a "timestamp"? If it is do *not* parse it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing this:

```
a,b = x.split('/')
```

This will work only if there are 2 elements after splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Just map to ints like this

```
x = '20/2020'
list(map(int,x.split('/'))) #[20, 2020]
```

Furthermore, you can refer to my previous answer to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541590/2695448)

Answer (score 0):

you can use map to get in int

```
>> list(map(int, x.split("/")))
>> [20, 2020]
```

You can change int to float if you want result in float

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> x.split() -> ['20/2020']
>   x.split("/") -> ["20","2020"]

Both of these are as expected.

`str.split()` returns a *list* (comparable to an array in many languages).

`str.split()` with no parameters will split on any whitespace, of which there is none in `'20/2020'`.

`str.split('/')` properly splits on the '/', giving you a list with 2 elements instead of one.

If you know your input will only ever contain a single '/', then you can get the 2 integers you need in a few ways. Here's a couple:

```
x = '20/2020'
x = x.split('/')
month = x[0]
year = x[1]
```

Or:

```
x = '20/2020'
month, year = x.split('/')
```

To understand why the second one works, you can see the answer here: [Assign multiple values of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426095/assign-multiple-values-of-a-list)